# How to conditionally copy and paste a from a table in one workbook to a table in another workbook in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Although I am relatively seasoned excel user, I am fairly new to VBA and am trying to tackle a fairly complicated task (at least it's complicated to me).

I have data in tables in 5 workbooks that I am trying to aggregate into one master workbook. However, I don't want all of the data. I only want to pull the data ( about 6 columns worth) that failed one of the tests (cell reads: "Fail").  All of the source workbooks have the 6 columns in the same order and have say "Pass" or "Fail" in their own cells.  I want to pull only the fails from each and paste into a master workbook. I would also like it to pull into a clean looking table (i.e no blank rows between each set of data).

I believe this is feasible, but it's above my skill level (right now). After hours and hours of research and trial and error that inevitably always ends in failure, I am about to wave the white flag. This is my last hope. Please help!

Comment: show sample data and sample result. just provide a link and i or somebody with enough rep will post it for you so you can get better response.

Comment: KEEP IT SIMP{LE. Just copy all the data over, and filter it at the destination workbook. Workbooks with external links are known as *broken workbooks*.

Answer (score 0):

The approach would be to:

1. Open all the workbooks to merge (assumed to be done manually, but could be coded if required)
2. Get a reference to the Master Table
3. Loop through open workbooks
4. Find the Table in the current workbook (code below assumes onlt one Table in each book.  IOf this is not the case, then it can be changed to use some distingusing feature of the required table)
5. Use `AutoFilter` to filter for "Fail" records.
6. Copy and Paste the data onto the end of the Master Table

This code demonstrates how to do this.  You will need to adapt it to tour specific situation.
Place this code in a Module in the Master workbook.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim loMaster As ListObject

    'Get Reference to Master table
    Set loMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").ListObjects(1)

    ' Loop through open workbooks
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            ' Assumes only one Table in each workbook,
            '  so return the first one found
            Set lo = Nothing
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                If ws.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
                    Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Not lo Is Nothing Then
                ' Filter Table on column Result for Fail
                lo.Range.AutoFilter _
                  Field:=lo.ListColumns("Result").Index, _
                  Criteria1:="Fail"

                ' Copy filterd data to Master Table
                If loMaster.InsertRowRange Is Nothing Then
                    'Master table is not empty
                    lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                      loMaster.DataBodyRange.Cells(loMaster.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
                Else
                    'Master table is empty
                    lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                      loMaster.InsertRowRange
                End If

                ' Reset Autofilter
                lo.Range.AutoFilter
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```